# How to install guest os (ubuntu server) in kvm without vnc?

Tags: ssh, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm absolutely new to KVM/QEMU. I used HyperV for a long time - but that was easy with a simple GUI ;)

So I've ssh access to a headless ubuntu server with kvm. Now I want to install another ubuntu server as vm - but I don't have VNC access.

```
virsh console [myvm]
```

just shows a blank screen

Would it be possible to install the guest os from within the ssh session of my host?

Comment: yes it is possible, you need to do text install and of course specify your console to OS console `ttyS0`.

Comment: @AizuddinZali then post this as answer. But could you add an short explanation why *of course* to use `ttyS0` and how I would specify this in my xml file? I would really appreciate this

Comment: I will once i have more time.Hopefully someone will post it first. For now i think this link should do good. [Guide](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1165804)

Comment: Any luck getting the console working? I have posted an answer, check it out.

Comment: I did not see your comment until yet. Woopsie. I'll test it later!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

KVM is very handy you can use VNC, Spice or Console to see the display.

The reason you seeing the blank screen is due to no screen redirection to host console, thus you cant see anything from `virsh console` command.

Redirect display to host serial port `TTYS0` and disable graphic install.

```
virt-install -n test -r 1024 --vcpus=1 --os-variant=rhel5.4 --accelerate --nographics -v  --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/shared-storage/test.img,size=20 --extra-args "console=ttyS0" --location /home/justin/Downloads/CentOS-5.7-x86_64-netinstall.iso
```

Above installation method only working if `virt-install` executed and running as **root**.

Note: Even you running as root, virt-install will switch the privileges to `qemu`. So workaround you can have `qemu` into `root` group.

This argument will be passed into `/proc/cmdline` and will be permenant.

The next time you want to access the console from host just need to execute `virsh console test`.

Comment: Is this also possible with an XML configuration. As I said I'm absolutely new and prefer the XML configuration so far (`virsh` instead of `virt-install`)

Comment: Those setting will be saved in XML format. In fact, each installation will resulted in XML configuration for each guest domain. You may find it in `/etc/libvirt/qemu/`. `virsh` is to control you guest/host domain, while `virt-install` is to install a guest domain. Both are for  different purposes.